# How is Row Total in order view calculated?

Tags: view

Fairly simple question. When viewing an order, ordered items are displayed under the Items Ordered section. How exactly is the Row Total calculated here for each item? Can anyone point me to a line where I can find the calculation/code for that specific number to show up? Doing some custom stuff and I want to use the same calculation for getting that specific number.

(Regardless of tax settings etc I want the same number that is shown under Row Total!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact calculation to get the item row total can be found under the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml` file at the very end of the template:

```
<?php echo $this->displayPrices(
            $_item->getBaseRowTotal() + $_item->getBaseTaxAmount() + $_item->getBaseHiddenTaxAmount() + Mage::helper('weee')->getBaseRowWeeeAmountAfterDiscount($_item) - $_item->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
            $_item->getRowTotal() + $_item->getTaxAmount() + $_item->getHiddenTaxAmount() + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeAmountAfterDiscount($_item) - $_item->getDiscountAmount()
        ); ?>
```

It could look a little bit complicated at first so the calculation could be simplified like a pseudo code like this:

```
row total = item row total + item tax amount + item hidden tax amount + item row wee amount after discount - item discount amount
```

Note that the first parameter of the `displayPrices` function represents the base item row total and the second one represents the item row total.

Those two parameters are then used in the `displayRoundedPrices` of the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php` and will be rendered differently depending on the currency of the order:

```
public function displayRoundedPrices($basePrice, $price, $precision=2, $strong = false, $separator = '<br />')
{
    if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
        $res = '';
        $res.= $this->getOrder()->formatBasePricePrecision($basePrice, $precision);
        $res.= $separator;
        $res.= $this->getOrder()->formatPricePrecision($price, $precision, true);
    }
    else {
        $res = $this->getOrder()->formatPricePrecision($price, $precision);
        if ($strong) {
            $res = '<strong>'.$res.'</strong>';
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks alot.

Missed the weee part which is why my calculations where wrong! Marking as accepted answer.

Though, what is the difference between BASE and /non base prises? (getBASERowTotal() vs getRowTotal() for example, the result is the same?).

Comment: hi i have same problem in magento2 can you help me for magento2